# Reactive springboot with netty server and swagger-ui

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-webflux, netty

I have a Reactive spring-boot application running on the netty server where the springboot version is 3.2.2 and Java 17. when I add a dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The /swagger-ui/index.html or /swagger-ui.html route does not return anything.

I tried bumping it down to open Swagger 2 but no luck.

Comment: for reactive spring boot (webflux) try `springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui` https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi?tab=readme-ov-file#spring-webflux-support-with-annotated-controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the high sight, It feels so dumb that I didn't notice there was a separate library for flux

As Alex pointed out, the solution to this problem is a change in dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
  <version>LATEST_RELEASE_VERION</version>
</dependency>
```